# Linq to Entities join into with DefaultIfEmpty returns no results

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Query below yields no results:

```
var query = from g in context.Groups
            join sl in context.GroupDancerLinks on g.Id equals sl.GroupId into sls
            join usl in context.GroupForeignDancerLinks on g.Id equals usl.GroupId into usls
            from sl in sls.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from usl in usls.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where usl.IsLead
            where sl.IsLead
            select new GroupGridDTO
            {
                Id = g.Id,
                LeadName = sl.Dancer.Name,
                UnregisteredLeadName = usl.ForeignDancer.Name,
                DancersCount = sls.Count(),
                ForeignDancersCount = usls.Count()
            };
```

However, when same query is modified to use FirstOrDefault, results are found:

```
var query = from g in context.Groups
            join sl in context.GroupDancerLinks on g.Id equals sl.GroupId into sls
            join usl in context.GroupForeignDancerLinks on g.Id equals usl.GroupId into usls
            select new GroupGridDTO
            {
                Id = g.Id,
                LeadName = sls.Where(sl => sl.IsLead).Select(sl => sl.Dancer.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                UnregisteredLeadName = usls.Where(usl => usl.IsLead).Select(usl => usl.ForeignDancer.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                DancersCount = sls.Count(),
                ForeignDancersCount = usls.Count()
            };
```

Looking on how queries are written, results should be the same. What is wrong with first query?

**EDIT:**

Tables "Groups" and "ForeignDancers" are related with M2M table "GroupForeignDancerLinks".

Tables "Groups" and "Dancers" are related with M2M table "GroupDancerLinks".

Comment: The queries most certainly should not be the same.  One should have N rows for each match (with a minimum of 1) and one should have exactly 1 row regardless of the number of matches.  That's not the same thing.

Comment: Would you mind rewriting query #2 without FirstOrDefault so it does the same functionality by using style of query #1?

Answer (score 1):

In the first query if a given row has `IsLead` as being false the row will be removed entirely.  In the second query the row exists, you just leave the corresponding item's name blank.

The queries are also semantically different if there are multiple matches for a given row in the left table.  The first will list all matching rows, the latter only the first.

Comment: Thank you for the theoretical explanation, would you mind providing query #2 rewritten without FirstOrDefault nested within select statement (style used with query #1)?

Comment: @BarisaPuter All you need to do is remove the `where` clauses for the conditions you apparently don't actually want to filter out, if you really do want those rows.

Comment: Problem is - if I already knew how to do that, I would do it myself. That's why I am asking for help :) I am having a confusion over DefaultIfEmpty and what is it supposed to do. Clearly it is not doing what I want, so I need to see what have I done wrong - code sample please! :)

Comment: @BarisaPuter And the whole point of this answer is that I'm telling you that your problem has literally *nothing* to do with `DefaultOrEmpty`.  It has to do with the fact that you're filtering out rows that it seems you want to keep.  If you want to keep those rows, you'll need to remove those filters.  That has nothing at all to do with `SelectMany` or `DefaultIfEmpty`.